# Ollydbg, F7, waitting for user input from dialog?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am new to reverse engineering,
When I step-in code in ollydbg with <kbd>F7</kbd>, until a dialog box appear, which waits for user input, how do I handle user-input in to program properly?

Comment: do you want to mange button click?

Answer (score 1):

`ollydbg 1.10` used for demo `2.01` has similar functionality

i assume your query to mean that once an input is provided and proceded further
by cliking a button etc how ot break back into user mode code

assuming you are working with a `simple application` that doesn't actively prevent anyone    from debugging
`pasuing` the application in ollydbg and `viewing call stack` should suffice

`press f12` (single threaded program assumed here or you need to select the right thread )

to pause the debuggee

`press ctrl+k` to view call stack

ollydbg will show both callee and caller  and in the context menu (right click) and has several options including execute till return to a specific call

`select any one of the call` in user code follow and set a breakpoint or

```
use execute till retn
```

[image: OLLYDBG CALL STACK]

the code for the call stack shown in snap is as follows MessageBox is waiting for an user input (for pressing ok)

```
before pressing ok pause (f12)  and view call stack (ctrl+k)
```

to see the cal lstack similar to the image

```
matryoshka:\>dir /b     matryoshka.cpp
matryoshka:\>type matryoshka.cpp

#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
void funcg (void) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Matryoshka Doll\n","Matryoshka Doll",MB_OK);    
}
void funcf (void) {
    funcg();
}
void funce (void) {
    funcf();
}
void funcd (void) {
    funce();
}
void funcc (void) {
    funcd();
}
void funcb (void) {
    funcc();
}
void funca (void) {
    funcb();
}
void main (void) {
    funca();
}
matryoshka:\>cl /Zi /analyze /W4 /nologo matryoshka.cpp /link /RELEASE
matryoshka:\>dir /b *.exe
matryoshka.exe

matryoshka:\>OLLYDBG.EXE matryoshka.exe
```